# python3.2) find minimum window in string: how to find minstart position in the string

Tags: python-3.x

I want to find minimum window with just only one input. I got stuck on deleting repeated alphabet that in string.

```
def window(string):
"""   
>>> window('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.')
'quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
"""
count1={}

for char in string.lower():
    if char.isalpha():
        if char not in count1: 
            count1[char]=1
        else: 
            count1[char]+=1

c=26
print(count1) #print how many alphabet exists in string(checking).
alphabet='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
start=0
minstart=0
end = 0

for end in range(0, len(alphabet)):
    if alphabet[end] in count1: 
        if count1[alphabet[end]]>0:
            count1[alphabet[end]]-=1
            if count1[alphabet[end].lower()]>=0:
                c-=1
print(count1)#print count1 that deleted alphabet(26) once.

if c==0:
    while True:#run while loop for 9 times
        for start in range(0, len(string)):
            if string[start].lower() in count1:
                if count1[string[start].lower()]>0:

                    minstart+=1
                    count1[alphabet[end]]-=1
```

At `if c==0:` line I tried to remove alphabet once from `count1`, and that make alphabets are almost became zero in `count1` and remains are `o:3,e:2,r:1,h:1,u:1,t:1`.

And I tried to remove `t`, `h`, `e` and find the minimum window start position (`minstart += 1`) but I'm not sure about this code.

Comment: What is the expected output from `The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.`?

Comment: Sorry. Forgot to mention about it. It's 'quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'. Thank you, Nurzhan.